# Migration from linq2sql to EF4.0

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework, repository-pattern

In linq2sql I had this code to implement base class for repository

```
    public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class {
        protected DataContext context;
        protected Table<T> table;

        public Repository (DataContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            table = context.GetTable<T> ();
        }

        public IQueryable<T> FindAll ()
        {
            return table;
        }

        public IQueryable<T> FindAll(Func<T, bool> exp)
        {
            return table.Where(exp).AsQueryable();
        }
}
```

Now I need to migrate to EF 4.0

Everything is fine and simple, BUT I can't find  **GetTable** (or similar) method in **ObjectContext**

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `CreateObjectSet<T>`.